# Strange datetime parsing error

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have a problem with parsing the date time from strings
[Here DOT NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/an0MbT)
here is my parsing code

```
var DateOfBirth2 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", "1924", "10", "19"));        
Console.WriteLine(DateOfBirth2);
var DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", "19", "10", "1924"));
Console.WriteLine(DateOfBirth);
```

The problem is `DateofBirth2` could be parsed succesfully, but `DateofBirth` could not and throwing string exception

> *System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*

The problem is exactly the same code could be parsed for both of the variables in different visual studio version.

What is the best way to parse, what is the reason of the error?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: It works on my pc, but it's probably your `CultureInfo`.

Comment: I accepted soners answer, tesekkurler sorun culture mis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings by default.

That means, your `CurrentCulture` have `yyyy-MM-dd` as a standard date and time format, but it doesn't have `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

In such a case, you can use custom date and time parsing with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) like;

```
string s = "19-10-1924";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Since you are from Turkey, I assume your `CurrentCulture` is `tr-TR` (like me) you can find all standard date and time format of your culture like;

```
foreach(var format in CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR").DateTimeFormat.
                      GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

Output will be;

```
dd.MM.yyyy
dd.MM.yy
yyyy-MM-dd
dd MMMM yyyy dddd
dd MMMM yyyy
dd MMMM yyyy dddd HH:mm
dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm
dd MMMM yyyy dddd HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
dd.MM.yy HH:mm
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM
dd MMMM
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
HH:mm
HH:mm:ss
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dd MMMM yyyy dddd HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM yyyy
MMMM yyyy
```

As you can see from output, `yyyy-MM-dd` is standard date and time format for `tr-TR` culture but not `dd-MM-yyyy` or `MM-dd-yyyy` formats.

Comment: Be careful using CurrentCulture for parsing something from external sources. A user may override its CurrentCulture settings and break your code

Comment: @DrKoch Yes, that's why I used `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR")` instead of `CulfureInfo.CurrentCulture` _even_ if I'm sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing a string in a specific Date-Format you should not rely on the default Format used by DateTime.Parse() which changes with current culture, ui culture and so on. A user may even override the current culture, making your code unreliable.

Use DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, provider) like so:

```
string s1 = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", "1924", "10", "19");
string s2 = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", "19", "10", "1924");

DateTime dateOfBirth1 = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd", s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateOfBirth2 =  DateTime.ParseExact("dd-MM-yyyy", s2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There is no `19` as a month in Gregorian calender.